# Concatenar registros SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, query, concatenação-de-string

Estou com um problema em uma query, onde preciso concatenar registros de uma tabela. Preciso que o `select` pegue o **`FormID`** e concatene os registros de **`AcaoID`** somente se **`Permitir`** for 1.

Query:

```
Declare @Result varchar(MAX) 
Declare @FormID varchar(MAX) 
Set @Result = ''
Select @FormID = FormID, @Result = COALESCE(@Result + AcaoID + '; ', '') FROM PermissaoAcoesForms 
where GrupoUsuario = '{0}' AND FormID = '{1}' AND Permitir = '1'
if  @Result <> '' Begin    
Set @Result = SUBSTRING(@Result, 1, LEN(@Result) - 1) end 
Select @FormID as FormID, @Result as AcaoID
```

O problema é que quando eu rodo a `query`, caso **`FormID`** exista e **`Permitir`** seja igual a 0, ele não retorna nada.

Nesse caso eu preciso retornar **`FormID`** independente do valor de **`Permitir`**, mas caso **`Permitir`** seja 1 ele tem que concatenar todos os registros onde **`Permitir`** seja 1.

Comment: Esses três campos são da mesma tabela? Se sim, eles já não retornam na mesma linha de consulta?

Comment: Sim sim, são da mesma tabela. Eu preciso retornar **`FormID`** independente do valor de **`Permitir`**, na minha query só retornar **`FormID`** caso **`Permitir`** seja 1

Comment: mas você esta declarando isso no where: "AND Permitir" = '1', se o valor de permitir não importa, basta tirar ele da cláusula

Comment: É que meu frontend exibe o resultado somente dos ativos (quando **`Permitir`** é igual a 1)

Answer (score -1):

Quando você quer fazer condições no SQL utilize CASE

```
Select CASE WHEN Permitir = '1' THEN CONCAT(FormID, AcaoID) ELSE FormID END 
FROM PermissaoAcoesForms
```

É isto que você precisa?

Comment: Mais ou menos isso, preciso concatenar os valores, Ex:
FormID = CarteiraCompras AcaoID = Imprimir; Visualizar